# How can I make my TCP Socket Server Async?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, asynchronous, tcpclient, tcplistener

I currently have made an all in one peer to peer 'chat' program. It currently uses a timer to receive messages, and a client to send them to other people running the program. I would really like to make this whole system async so I stop getting complaints of the main executable freezing and such.

I have pasted all of my code(VB.net) here: http://pastebin.com/EcrtCgVc

Could someone assist me in making this system faster, async, or done better.

If you would like a link to the dropbox of the full source, I can provide this also.

Comment: This is not a ***gimmez dA codez*** kind of site. Have you even read about the async socket methods?  Ask about specific problems in your design or about specific problems when trying to use the async methods. However, start by breaking out the socket code into a own class. Don't mix GUI code with business code. You could also try out my networking library Griffin.Networking. Here is a sample chat client/server: https://github.com/jgauffin/Samples/tree/master/Griffin.Networking/ChatServerClient

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at this example project:

> Asynchronous Server Socket Example
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You can use it together with this example:

> Asynchronous Client Socket Example
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You may need to use async methods in your server code and you may use Delegate Sub to make your server run in another thread, so main thread(UI) will be still responsive.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172879.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Without looking at your code, I am also working with socket programming.
"Do not mix GUI code with business code."
Like jgauffin said, you should not combine code that run in the background with the GUI.

For example, if you're using a socket to accept data, or connections, you must run that method on a new thread.
Example...

```
Public Sub YourMainSub()
    Dim threadOne As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ListenCode)
    threadOne.Start()
    'Put other code here.....
End Sub
Public Sub ListenCode()
    Dim newPerson = yourServer.Accept()
    'Or
    Dim newData = yourServer.Receive()
End Sub
```

*Sorry if the code isn't exactly correct. I typed that by memory.*